# Extension Fields, complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory, extension-field

I have a question about the complex numbers given as an extension field.

I know that complex numbers can be seen as $\mathbb{R}\left[x\right]/<x^2+1>$ (Well, I really don't know it yet, because I haven't understood the argument). But I don't understand why is that in Fraleigh they say that this field consists in all elements of the form $a+b\alpha$ where $\alpha=x+<x^2+1>$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. If I replace in $a+b\alpha$ it becomes:
$a+bx+b<x^2+1>$.
But i thought the set $\mathbb{R}\left[x\right]/<x^2+1>$ consisted in the elements of the form $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k+<x^2+1>$ where $a_i=0$ for all but a finite number of values of $i$. How can I show that it's the same? And is it really the same?

I know that $\alpha$ plays the role of $i$, but...

Comment: It is the same because $x^2=-1 mod \langle x^2+1 \rangle$

Comment: Oh, that's it. Facepalm of me.

Comment: On understanding the argument: Have you heard of the omni-important [isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem_2) (for rings) yet? If not, look at it. As soon as you got that, take as a first example the ring homomorphism $ℝ[X] → ℂ,~X ↦ \mathrm i$ and determine its kernel.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that theorem. Thanks. My big problem was the one that marwalix solved.